More succinct way to write repetitive JSON_EXTRACT?
Is there a more succinct way to write this BigQuery SQL:
select
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(DATA, '$.cloned[1].name') AS cloned_1_name,
  JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,        '$.cloned[1].value') AS cloned_1_value,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(DATA, '$.cloned[2].name') AS cloned_2_name,
  JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,        '$.cloned[2].value') AS cloned_2_value,
  JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(DATA, '$.cloned[3].name') AS cloned_3_name,
  JSON_EXTRACT(DATA,        '$.cloned[3].value') AS cloned_3_value,
from `foo.bar.my_table`

This array has 100 elements, so easy to copy/paste but ugly to maintain.  I asked Gemini but it provided SQL that gives a syntax error of Syntax error: Unexpected keyword UNNEST at [3:5]:
WITH extracted_cloned AS (
  SELECT
    UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(DATA, '$.cloned')) AS cloned
  FROM `foo.bar.my_table`
)
SELECT
  cloned.name AS cloned_name,
  cloned.value AS cloned_value,
FROM extracted_cloned


The syntax for unnest is to use it in the SELECT clause... SELECT * FROM table CROSS JOIN unnest(blah) AS blah (always read the manual)

Interesting that Gemini AI got is so wrong...

Explore below approach
SELECT * EXCEPT(data)
FROM (
  SELECT data, OFFSET + 1 AS pos,
    JSON_EXTRACT_SCALAR(cloned, '$.name') AS name,
    JSON_EXTRACT(cloned, '$.value') AS VALUE
  FROM `foo.bar.my_table`,
  UNNEST(JSON_EXTRACT_ARRAY(DATA, '$.cloned')) AS cloned WITH OFFSET
)
PIVOT (ANY_VALUE(name) AS name, ANY_VALUE(VALUE) AS VALUE FOR pos IN (1,2,3,4))   


Very cool!  Any way to get the IN (1,2,3,4) to be more like a range?  I am looking to have 100 values, so something like IN (1..100) ?

I tried IN (generate_array(1,100)) but that led to "PIVOT IN list item must be type INT64 to match the PIVOT FOR expression; found ARRAY".  There's likely a trick I'm missing here.

syntax of pivot requires that part to be a literal. the way to handle this situation is via  use of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE - you can search here - I have number of answers using such technique
